# Doubt in solving inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was working with inequalities and came across this question, I have underlined the step which I don't understand.

It goes like this,
$$4x^2-64x+249≥0$$
Implies,
$$x^2-64x+\frac{249}{4}≥0$$

I approached my teacher thinking  it was a typo but he told me it was not.

[image]

Comment: It is a typo: it should be $-16x$, not $-64x$

Comment: @A.Goodier, that's what I was thinking but teacher declined and Alex me to follow the next step

Comment: As written, the implication is false, e.g. take $x=10$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be $16x$ and this is a typo. This claim is substantiated by what is done in the next step: 
$$(x-8)^2+\frac{249}{4}-64=x^2-16x+\frac{249}{4}$$
which is what you have in mind as well.